Power bi data source with parameter based on query
I have a power bi report, which pulls data from oracle DB. It contains a parameter FYEAR which is created based on a query. I want to add this parameter inside the  datasource query, connected to oracle database, I created parameter like below
I know we can pull the data from the data source and then apply filter using the parameter on top of the pulled data. But I want to use this parameter and filter the records while pulling from the database itself.
Here is my power bi data source code
= Odbc.Query("dsn=Ora_db", "  select * from customer where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ASOFDATE)="&FYEAR&"")

I got the below error message when I tried the above code

I changed the datasource privacy level, but there is no luck. Anyone has idea how I can use query based parameter inside the datasource while pulling from the database
